# Is there a way to have a System.out.print print something different once in a loop?

Tags: java, loops

I'm very new to coding, and one of my projects was to create a program that uses a while loop to ask a user for test grades and find the average. The problem I have is that when it asks for the first grade, my instructor wants it to also print out "Enter -1 when you're finished" along with the first grade only. He wants the results to look something like this.

```
Test grade1? (Enter -1 when you are finished): random grade
Test grade2? random grade
Test Grade3? random grade
The average of your test grades is: average of all grades
```

Currently, I have the first grade as a separate line of code that asks the user and it is not in the loop. Is there any way to combine it into the loop and still have it to ask "Enter -1 when you're finished" but for only the first test grade?

P.s Sorry if my code is very messy I'm still not very good at it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class U4D3 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Test grade 1? (Enter -1 when you're finished): ");
        int grade1 = scan.nextInt();
     
         int i = 2;
         int testCounter = 1;
         int sum = 0;
         boolean flag = true;
     
      while(flag) {
        System.out.print("Test grade " + i + "? ");
        int grades = scan.nextInt();
            if (grades == -1){  
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        sum = grade1 + grades;
        grade1 = sum;
        i++;
        testCounter++;
           
        }
      System.out.println("The averages of your test grades is: " + (double)sum/testCounter);
   }
}
```

Comment: can you show your desired `input` and `output`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check with an `if` statement whether it's the first test and display the additional message if that's the case.
Also you can get rid of the `i` variable and use `testCounter` in it's place. You also don't need the `flag`, just using `break` is enough.
At the end of the loop the `testCounter` will be off by one so you have to decrement by one when calculating the average (`(testCounter - 1)`).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class U4D3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCounter = 1;
    int sum = 0;

    while (true) {
      System.out.print("Test grade " + testCounter + "? ");
      if (testCounter == 1)
        System.out.print("(Enter -1 when you're finished): ");
      int grade = scan.nextInt();
      if (grade == -1) {
        break;
      }
      sum += grade;
      testCounter++;
    }
    System.out.println("The averages of your test grades is: " + (double) sum / (testCounter - 1));
  }
}
```